# Fatal Error in tm (text mining) document term matrix creation

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

`tm` is throwing an error when I try to create a document term matrix

```
library(tm)
data(crude)

#control parameters
dtm.control <- list(
    tolower           = TRUE, 
    removePunctuation = TRUE,
    removeNumbers     = TRUE,
    stopWords         = stopwords("english"),
    stemming          = TRUE, # false for sentiment
    wordLengths       = c(3, "inf"))

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp, control = dtm.control)
```

Error:

> Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  : 
>     'i, j, v' different lengths
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
>     all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
>   2: In simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  :
>     NAs introduced by coercion

What am I doing wrong?
Also:

I am using these tutorials:

- [Basic Text Mining](http://begriffs.com/posts/2015-02-25-text-mining-in-r.html)
- [Text Mining in R](http://begriffs.com/posts/2015-02-25-text-mining-in-r.html)

Are there better/ more recent walkthroughs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider a few changes in your code, especially removeStopWords and creating a corpus.  Below worked for me:

```
library(tm)
data("crude")

#control parameters
dtm.control <- list(
  tolower           = TRUE, 
  removePunctuation = TRUE,
  removeNumbers     = TRUE,
  removestopWords   = TRUE,
  stemming          = TRUE, # false for sentiment
  wordLengths       = c(3, "inf"))

corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(crude))

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp, control = dtm.control)

> inspect(dtm)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 20, terms: 848)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1877/15083
Sparsity           : 89%
Maximal term length: 16
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the exact same error. R 3.1.2, tm 0.6.

Comment: It seems that removing stemming from the list works. But why?

Comment: I am on 3.1.0 (now feeling a bit behind the times) and tm 0.6, with Windows 8.  Just re-ran my posted code above and it was fine.  Would you restart R and try again, since sometimes perverse gremlins accumulate?